# AudioServicesPlaySystemSound fails first time for key press sound?

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

I am using straight calls to the system sounds, such as:

AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(0x450)

to get the a button press to sound like a standard iOS keyboard click.

It works mostly, except it seems that the first time a view appears, somehow the first attempt at playing the sound does not work. The button press that is also calling AudioServicesPlaySystemSound is indeed happening.

Any ideas why the sound is stifled the first time I invoke it?

Comment: FWIW I'm experiencing this, 4 months after original post, on iOS 8.1.3.

Comment: experiencing the same issue;